# Moq Callback value does not change when callback is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I wana create a mock object where everytime the method GetPath is called i get's iterated.
Here is my unit testing code:

```
string fileSharePath = "/fileSharePath/";
int i = 0;
m_FileShareDocumentPathProvider.Setup(p => p.GetPath(It.IsAny<IFileShareDocument>()))                                    
                               .Callback(() =>
                                   {
                                       i++;
                                       fileSharePath += i;
                                   })
                               .Returns(fileSharePath);
```

Here is the code In witch GetPath get's called:

```
foreach (var document in documents)
{
     string filePath = GetFilePath(document);
     fileSharePaths.Add(filePath);
     documentsDictionary.Add(document, filePath);
}

private string GetFilePath(IFileShareDocument document)
{
     var fileShareDocumentPathProvider = m_FileShareDocumentPathProviderFactory.GetFilePathProvider(document);
     var filePath = fileShareDocumentPathProvider.GetPath(document);
     return filePath;
}
```

While debugging I notice the value of fileSharePath does not change as expected , it stays the same.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
  m_FileShareDocumentPathProviderFactory.Setup(f => f.GetFilePathProvider(It.IsAny<IFileShareDocument>()))
                                              .Returns(m_FileShareDocumentPathProvider.Object);
```

Comment: Have you configured `m_FileShareDocumentPathProviderFactory.GetFilePathProvider` to actually return the right mock object (`m_FileShareDocumentPathProvider`)?

Comment: Yes I have configured it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change `Returns(fileSharePath)` to `Returns(()=>fileSharePath)`.  When you call `Returns`, it passes `fileSharePath` by value, so that value never changes.  You have to pass it in as a delegate, which causes Moq to execute that function each time it "returns" the value.

In fact you can shorten your code by eliminating the `Callback` and just doing `.Returns(() => fileSharePath += ++i)`.  You should rarely need to use both `Callback` *and* `Returns` for a single function.  `Callback` "mock executes" a `void` function, and `Return` "mock executes" a function with a return value, and then returns that value.